# Binomial-Multinomial Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, multinomial-distribution

In probability theory, what is the difference between binomial and multinomial distribution?
According to my understanding, binomial distribution has 2 outcomes, whereas multinomial distribution has >2 outcomes

Comment: Yes. That is it.